# Find nth TD in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to get find out the value(td text) in column C if I click on any cell in the same row

```
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| A        | B        | C   | D        | E        | F        | G        |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| click me | click me | ok1 | click me | click me | click me | click me |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| click me | click me | ok2 | click me | click me | click me | click me |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| click me | click me | ok3 | click me | click me | click me | click me |
+----------+----------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```

I have tried the following with an onclick event but nothing:

```
var tellMe = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(2)').text();

alert(tellMe) //ok1 | ok2 | ok3
```

Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisG could you post the entire syntax? thanks

Comment: Never mind, code works fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/h3encLbt/

Comment: @ChrisG Fantastic! thanks!!